# ImageView dissapearing after setting an ID

Tags: android, layout, view, imageview, onclicklistener

I'm programatically adding views into my layout inside a for loop.

The xml file of the layout I'm adding is like this one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_consulta_item_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_consulta_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LinearLayout_dados_consulta"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/LinearLayout_dados_consulta"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="70dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/estrela_off" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_dados_consulta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView_consulta_action"
        android:background="#660000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/origem"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffaaaa"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_origem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="YYY"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#eeeeee" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/data_ida"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffaaaa"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_data_ida"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2014-05-05"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#eeeeee"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my main_activity, I call the constructor:

```
for (int i=0;i<resultList.length-1;i++){

    RelativeLayout viewToLoad = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.consulta_item, null);
                ll.addView(viewToLoad);

    ImageView ImgConsulta_action = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_consulta_action);

    LinearLayout dados_consulta = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_dados_consulta);


    dados_consulta.setOnLongClickListener(...);
    ImgConsulta_action.setOnLongClickListener(...);
```

Well, I keep setting SetText for all the views in the layout and so on.

But, in order to make the setOnClickListener to work for each view, I must set a id to the views inside the for loop:

```
dados_consulta.setId(4000+i);
ImgConsulta_action.setId(5000+i); //(*lastline)
```

The weird thing is happening is that:

If I comment this last line, the layout is inserted correctly with the imageview showing a star as it is suposed to do and the listener at "dados_consulta" works fine.

But if I remove the comment at this last line, the star dissapear from the screen.

Can anybody help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: Are there any other places in your code where you use this line: `ImageView ImgConsulta_action = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_consulta_action);` ??

Comment: please, post the code portion with the code snippet which causing the problem.

Comment: @Merlevede No, this is the only place. The other lines I call for ImgConsulta_action is to set tag, onClickListener, setImageResource and setId. Wich, by the way, is the peace of code that cause the problem

Comment: @HamidShatu I did post the line that make the imageview disapear. (At least, I believe this is the line because if I remove it the image appears!) I don't understand why this question is not clear. Maybe is useful to add that the setOnClickListener calls a void that opens a AlertDialog. But I don't think that this makes any difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an layout params referenced to the ID of the layout elements at the original view.
Since I have to change the ID dynamically while I'm adding this layout several times into my activity, I also need to reset the layoutparams to the new Ids.
So, I added this lines:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)ImgConsulta_action.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, dados_consulta.getId());
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, dados_consulta.getId());

ImgConsulta_action.setLayoutParams(params);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsDadosConsulta = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)dados_consulta.getLayoutParams();
paramsDadosConsulta.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
paramsDadosConsulta.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, ImgConsulta_action.getId());

dados_consulta.setLayoutParams(paramsDadosConsulta);
```

Now it's working perfectly.

Notice that the problem is not about the layout disappearing it was about a layout get in front of the other one. (making this other one invisible)